# Number of possibilities in a partition problem

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

Given a set of n items, how many possibilities are there, to distribute these items in two sets with $\dfrac{n}{2}$ items, each?

I came up with something like $\dfrac{n!}{\dfrac{n}{2}!}$ but the results doesnt seem right.

Comment: Presumably, $n$ is even?

Comment: Yes, _n_ has to be even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to choose $n/2$ items from $n$ items . When you select any $n/2$ items it automatically forms two sets of $n/2$ items each .

So the number of ways of choosing $n/2$ items from $n$  items is simply $$n\choose{n/2}$$

Comment: Which (to compare with the question) is $\dfrac{n!}{\left(\tfrac{n}{2}!\right)^2}$